# attempt to index a nil value (global 'random') lua problem

Tags: lua

Hi I am new to lua and i was watching this tutorial about it and the person showed me this code

```
io.write("Your cash is: ",random.math(1,100))
```

I tried to do it on my online compiler and the error above showed up
I think it was because he was using an older version of lua because it was uploaded in 2015, so can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You simply have a typo. Checkout: ```io.write("Your cash is: ",math.random(1,100))```

Answer (score 2):

Lua by default doesn't have a `random` library, this is why `random` is returning nil. You are probably looking for `math.random`:

```lua
io.write("Your cash is: ", math.random(1,100)) -- this is valid lua
```

Comment: @Chips please accept the answer clicking on the icon bellow the votes.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever online compiler you are using doesn't have `random` library or you've accidentally overwritten the variable somewhere.

You can write `print( random )` to the very top of your code. If it says nil, then you don't have the random library.